# Need help to develop CHEF recipe to execute 4 bash scripts on 4 servers in sequence and verify if each script executed successfully

Tags: bash, shell, execute, chef-recipe

I need help to develop CHEF recipe to automate application installation.

Here is my requirement -

Well, I have 4 different bash scripts and need to execute on 4 different severs in sequence like script 'A' to execute on server '1' and verify that script executed successful and then script 'B' to execute on server '2' and again verify execution. similarly for other 2 scripts to execute on 2 different servers.

Any ideas to develop recipe for above requirement??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes are usually independent from each other. If you still want to do this I would recommend using a `data bag` that stores the outcome of the scripts or alternatively a `node tag` about the outcome that you can query in the chef client runs before executing the script.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I will try that :)